# React Native countdown timer cut down the text input focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have been developing **OTP** screen so i need a timer to restrict user for atleast 30 seconds to request again the otp.so i developed a timer using states  with  setInterval.timer is working fine but while timer is running, **it is quite hard for the user to type the OTP as OTP Text Input loses focus** when the state update so i need a fix for that.i am using **"react-native-otp-inputs": "^7.0.3"**
I also tried to render the timer as a seperate component but still same problem occurs

Comment: Please post some source code so that the problem can be identified.

Comment: problem solved with react-native-countdown-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly it's because when you set the state in setInterval component re-render again and input filed losing its focus. I recommend you to use this 3rd party package for countdown [react-native-countdown-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component)